# getSupportActionBar error

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new to android development. I want to create my custom actionbar. I've encountered this problem: if I declare actionBar `mActionBar = getActionBar();`
my app crashes at runtime. But if I use `getSupportActionBar()` I can't compile with the follow error: incompatible types. I've tried all possible implementation but it's still not working. I'm using android studio. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.sample_search);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }


}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.search_bar" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you given your Activity a non-actionbar theme in the Manifest ?

Comment: update post with manifest

Comment: can you post your gradle file? Only the dependencies part

Comment: where i can find it? u mean android tab log? sry im noob

Comment: Error:(17, 51) error: incompatible types: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar cannot be converted to android.app.ActionBar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have imported

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
```

this and not this

```
android.app.ActionBar
```

Comment: I do all correctly add dependancy of ``com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`` and Toolbar ``android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`` and then when I want to import v7.app.ActionBar it doesn't work and v7 not resolved! what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBar` is not used anymore since the Lollipop (API 21) update.
You shall be using `Toolbar`, which is now a official part of the support library.

Basically, you declare the toolbar in your res/layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
    android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

and then, in your activity, instantiate and set it as the support action bar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

You neeed to include the support library in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```